# How can I set a simple forwarding procmail rule based on FROM?

Tags: email, procmail

Using Procmail, I would like to add a rule that dictates:

If any email comes from this specific email address, *in addition to delivering it locally*, also forward it to this other email address.

My attempt at this rule is as follows:

```
:0 c:
* ^From:.sender@example.com
! recipient@horses.example
```

... but this does not appear to work.  In fact, it appears to not do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should provide debugging details with an example of the message you are testing with; but we can speculate:

- Maybe the regex doesn't match.  Perhaps you actually mean

  ```
  :0c
  * ^From:(.*\<)?sender@example\.com
  ! recipient@horses.example
  ```

  Notice also the absence of a second colon after the `c` flag
  (you cannot meaningfully use a lock file here, nor should you)
  and the addition of a backslash before the `.com`
  to only match a literal dot, not any character.
- Maybe you are not calling Procmail at all.

  Can you demonstrate that Procmail actually gets run when you receive mail?  Perhaps see also https://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Comment: Thank you very much.  I used your exact syntax and formatting and now it is working properly.  Yes, mailserver and procmail were already working - I was already doing other procmail rules, etc. - just couldn't get this very simple one worded just right.  Thank you again.

Comment: The link also has some useful tips for how to test things. Thanks for the accept!